# Data extracted from Excel is different than the one in database. It's appearing as "=-" in Excel but "-" in database table

Tags: sql-server, excel

As per title. Not sure what to do to extract the correct data format.

Screenshots:

[image: In excel, appear as #NAME?]

[image: In database]

Comment: "=" means the start of a formula in Excel, hence why you also have a "#NAME?" error. You need to start it with "'" (single quote) if you want it to be treated as a string.

Answer (score 0):

If you are copy pasting to Excel, first format the column as text and then try to paste the data. You can use the Data->Get Data->From Database in Excel to directly extract the table data from database and the columns will be formatted automatically.